# Booting Android 4.2.1 on Pandaboard

Tags: android, boot, android-4.2-jelly-bean, pandaboard

I'm trying to boot `Android 4.2.1` on `PandaBoard`. I got the resources from [here](http://blog.sola-dolphin-1.net/archives/4334161.html). Though, there was no problem while building, it gets crashed while booting.

I tried it in both Panda4430 and Panda4460 boards.

When I tried it in Panda4430, it didn't get into the kernel booting phase.

The console output was,

```
3725412 bytes read
## Booting image at 80000000 ...
   Image Name:   Linux-3.0.31-g4a094a5-dirty
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    3725348 Bytes =  3.6 MB
   Load Address: 80008000
   Entry Point:  80008000
   Verifying Checksum ... OK
OK
I2C read: I/O error

Starting kernel ...

Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.
```

I used the following bootargs for Panda4430:

```
setenv bootargs androidboot.console=ttyO2 console=ttyO2,115200n8 mem=456M@0x80000000 mem=512M@0xA0000000 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootdelay=2 init=/init vram="32M" omapf0
setenv bootcmd 'mmcinit 0; fatload mmc 0 0x80000000 uImage;bootm 80000000'
boot.
```

When I tried it in Panda4460, it got crashed.

The following is the log obtained using logcat.

```
shell@android:/ $
shell@android:/ $ logcat
--------- beginning of /dev/log/main
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim: Inside main
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim:ST built into the kernel ?
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim:BT driver module un-available...
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim:BT driver built into the kernel ?
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim:FM driver module un-available...
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim:FM driver built into the kernel ?
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim:GPS driver module un-available...
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim:GPS driver built into the kernel ?
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim:FM V4L2 driver module un-available...
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim:FM V4L2 driver built into the kernel ?
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim:found bluetooth rfkill entry @ 0
E/uim-sysfs(   91):
E/uim-sysfs(   91): uim:changed permissions for /sys/class/rfkill/rfkill0/state(0)
E/uim-sysfs(   91):
I/installd(   98): installd firing up
E/cutils  (   98): Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
E/installd(   98): Could not create directories; exiting.
E/keystore(   99): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
--------- beginning of /dev/log/system
I/Vold    (   88): Vold 2.1 (the revenge) firing up
E/Vold    (   88): Error reading configuration (No such file or directory)... continuing anyways
I/DEBUG   (   93): debuggerd: Feb  8 2013 18:31:46
I/Netd    (   92): Netd 1.0 starting
W/InterfaceController(   92): Warning (Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface coy
I/SurfaceFlinger(   94): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger(   94): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
E/libEGL  (   94): eglGetDisplay:121 error 300c (EGL_BAD_PARAMETER)
E/libEGL  (   94): eglInitialize:137 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
I/gralloc (   94): using (fd=14)
I/gralloc (   94): id           = omapfb
I/gralloc (   94): xres         = 1280 px
I/gralloc (   94): yres         = 720 px
I/gralloc (   94): xres_virtual = 1280 px
I/gralloc (   94): yres_virtual = 1440 px
I/gralloc (   94): bpp          = 32
I/gralloc (   94): r            = 16:8
I/gralloc (   94): g            =  8:8
I/gralloc (   94): b            =  0:8
I/gralloc (   94): width        = 203 mm (160.157639 dpi)
I/gralloc (   94): height       = 114 mm (160.421051 dpi)
I/gralloc (   94): refresh rate = 73.12 Hz
E/ti_hwc  (   94): Composer HAL failed to load compatible Graphics HAL
E/SurfaceFlinger(   94): composer device failed to initialize (Invalid argument)
W/SurfaceFlinger(   94): getting VSYNC period from fb HAL: 13676897
E/libEGL  (   94): validate_display:245 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
F/libc    (   94): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 123 (SurfaceFlinger)
I/DEBUG   (   93): failed to open tombstone file '/data/tombstones/tombstone_00': No such file or directory
I/mediaserver(   97): ServiceManager: 0x40de0e30
I/AudioFlinger(   97): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
I/CameraService(   97): CameraService started (pid=97)
I/AudioPolicyManagerBase(   97): loadAudioPolicyConfig() loaded /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
I/AudioFlinger(   97): loadHwModule() Loaded primary audio interface from OMAP4 audio HW HAL (audio) handle 1
I/AudioFlinger(   97): HAL output buffer size 1920 frames, normal mix buffer size 1920 frames
I/AudioMixer(   97): found effect "Multichannel Downmix To Stereo" from The Android Open Source Project
I/AudioFlinger(   97): Using module 1 has the primary audio interface
I/AudioFlinger(   97): AudioFlinger's thread 0x40de9fb8 ready to run
W/AudioFlinger(   97): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
W/AudioFlinger(   97): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
I/audio_a2dp_hw(   97): adev_open:  adev_open in A2dp_hw module
I/AudioFlinger(   97): loadHwModule() Loaded a2dp audio interface from A2DP Audio HW HAL (audio) handle 3
I/AudioPolicyService(   97): Loaded audio policy from LEGACY Audio Policy HAL (audio_policy)
D/AndroidRuntime(  163):
D/AndroidRuntime(  163): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime(  163): CheckJNI is OFF
D/MDnsDS  (   92): MDnsSdListener::Hander starting up
D/MDnsDS  (   92): MDnsSdListener starting to monitor
D/MDnsDS  (   92): Going to poll with pollCount 1
E/dalvikvm(  163): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/core.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/core.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  163): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/core-junit.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@core-junit.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/core-junit.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  163): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/bouncycastle.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@bouncycastle.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  163): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/ext.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@ext.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/ext.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  163): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/framework.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@framework.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/framework.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  163): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/telephony-common.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@telephony-common.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/telephony-common.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  163): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/mms-common.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@mms-common.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/mms-common.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  163): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/android.policy[   86.676879] init: untracked pid 995 exited
.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@android.policy.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/android.policy.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  163): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/services.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@services.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/services.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  163): Could not stat dex cache directory '/data/dalvik-cache': No such file or directory
I/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to open or create cache for /system/framework/apache-xml.jar (/data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@apache-xml.jar@classes.dex)
D/dalvikvm(  163): Unable to process classpath element '/system/framework/apache-xml.jar'
E/dalvikvm(  163): No valid entries found in bootclasspath '/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ex'
E/dalvikvm(  163): VM aborting
F/libc    (  163): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 163 (zygote)
I/DEBUG   (   93): failed to open tombstone file '/data/tombstones/tombstone_00': No such file or directory
I/ServiceManager(   87): service 'media.audio_policy' died
I/ServiceManager(   87): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
I/ServiceManager(   87): service 'media.player' died
I/ServiceManager(   87): service 'media.camera' died
I/Netd    (  325): Netd 1.0 starting
W/InterfaceController(  325): Warning (Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:745): library "/system/lib/libnetcmdiface.so" not found) while opening the net interface coy
I/mediaserver(  324): ServiceManager: 0x40a9be30
I/AudioFlinger(  324): Using default 3000 mSec as standby time.
I/CameraService(  324): CameraService started (pid=324)
I/AudioPolicyManagerBase(  324): loadAudioPolicyConfig() loaded /system/etc/audio_policy.conf
I/AudioFlinger(  324): loadHwModule() Loaded primary audio interface from OMAP4 audio HW HAL (audio) handle 1
I/AudioFlinger(  324): HAL output buffer size 1920 frames, normal mix buffer size 1920 frames
I/AudioMixer(  324): found [   86.894531] request_suspend_state: wakeup (0->0) at 86888305667 (1970-01-01 00:01:26.883666996 UTC)
effect "Multichannel Downmix To Stereo" from The Android Open Source Project
I/AudioFlinger(  324): Using modul[   86.914154] init: untracked pid 777 exited
e 1 has the primary audio interface
I/AudioFlinger(  324): AudioFlinger's threa[   86.923431] init: untracked pid 776 exited
d 0x40039008 ready to run
W/AudioFlinger(  324): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
W/AudioFlinger(  324): Thread AudioOut_2 cannot connect to the power manager service
I/audio_a2dp_hw(  324): adev_open:  adev_open in A2dp_hw module
I/AudioFlinger(  324): loadHwModule() Loaded a2dp audio interface from A2DP Audio HW HAL (audio) handle 3
I/AudioPolicyService(  324): Loaded audio policy from LEGACY Audio Policy HAL (audio_policy)
D/MDnsDS  (  325): MDnsSdListener starting to monitor
D/MDnsDS  (  325): MDnsSdListener::Hander starting up
D/MDnsDS  (  325): Going to poll with pollCount 1
E/keystore(  538): chdir: /data/misc/keystore: No such file or directory
I/installd(  537): installd firing up
E/cutils  (  537): Failed to read /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory
E/installd(  537): Could not create directories; exiting.
I/SurfaceFlinger(  536): SurfaceFlinger is starting
I/SurfaceFlinger(  536): SurfaceFlinger's main thread ready to run. Initializing graphics H/W...
E/libEGL  (  536): eglGetDisplay:121 error 300c (EGL_BAD_PARAMETER)
E/libEGL  (  536): eglInitialize:137 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
I/gralloc (  536): using (fd=14)
I/gralloc (  536): id           = omapfb
I/gralloc (  536): xres         = 1280 px
I/gralloc (  536): yres         = 720 px
I/gralloc (  536): xres_virtual = 1280 px
I/gralloc (  536): yres_virtual = 1440 px
I/gralloc (  536): bpp          = 32
I/gralloc (  536): r            = 16:8
I/gralloc (  536): g            =  8:8
I/gralloc (  536): b            =  0:8
I/gralloc (  536): width        = 203 mm (160.157639 dpi)
I/gralloc (  536): height       = 114 mm (160.421051 dpi)
I/gralloc (  536): refresh rate = 73.12 Hz
E/ti_hwc  (  536): Composer HAL failed to load compatible Graphics HAL
E/SurfaceFlinger(  536): composer device failed to initialize (Invalid argument)
W/SurfaceFlinger(  536): getting VSYNC period from fb HAL: 13676897
E/libEGL  (  536): validate_display:245 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
F/libc    (  536): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 539 (SurfaceFlinger)
I/DEBUG   (   93): failed to open tombstone file '/data/tombstones/tombstone_00': No such file or directory
D/AndroidRuntime(  541):
D/AndroidRuntime(  541): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit <<<<<<
```

Then the logs get repeated form this line.

I used the follwing bootargs for Panda4460:

```
setenv bootargs androidboot.console=ttyO2 console=ttyO2,115200n8 mem=1G root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw rootdelay=2 init=/init vram="64M"
setenv bootcmd 'mmcinit 0; fatload mmc 0 0x80000000 uImage;bootm 80000000'
boot
```

Please guide me to solve this issue.

Comment: Check if your init.rc is completely executed . Looks more of a build issue

Comment: how are you flashing the SD card?fastboot?What is the make of the SD-card?

Answer (score 0):

I think you download the AOSP and compile it for flashing. And then you get this bug: the device does not draw any thing to the screen.

And in the logcat, you found surfaceflinger crashed.

I met this problem in maguro device because of many un-opensource code not being contained in the AOSP. Detail crash log is http://www.5wpc.info/it/technical/os/android/2014/10/31/AOSP/

You can download these binaries in the https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/drivers#magurojdq39,
and then you remake it for patching.